# Closure with typed arguments in Groovy

Tags: groovy, closures, static-typing, groovy++

I'd like to be more explicit about my closures regarding their argument types.  So I would write something like

```
List<Y> myCollect(List<X> list, Closure<X,Y> clos) { ... }
```

I know that Groovy won't use that type information, but Groovy++ may use it at compile time.  Can this be be achieved (other than putting it into a comment)?

UPDATE:
The title may sound misleading, but I thought the above example would make it clearer.  I'm interested in specifying types of a closure which is the argument of some function.  Suppose, I want to redefince the built-in `collect`.  So I'm interested in writing `myCollect`, not in writing `clos`.  What I want to achieve is get compile time errors

```
myCollect(['a', 'ab'], { it / 2 }) // compile error
myCollect(['a', 'ab'], { it.size() })  // OK
```

Comment: In the type Closure<V>, the V represents the return value of the closure, not its parameters.  As such, it wouldn't make sense to have a Closure<V, X> since you can't return two values.

Comment: I mean `Closure<X,Y>` to accept a single `X` as input and returns `Y`.  So it can be applied to the items of `List<X>`.  I updated the return type of the function.

Comment: now the accepted answer should be the one from 
Richard Vowles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23887505/1915920 since it regards the redefinition of the closure interface/function and related type checks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define the types of a closure's parameters, but the syntax shown above is incorrect. Here is a closure without parameter types:

```
def concatenate = {arg1, arg2 ->
  return arg1 + arg2
}
```

And here is the same closure with parameter types

```
def concatenate = {String arg1, String arg2 ->
  return arg1 + arg2
}
```

> I know that Groovy won't use that type information, but Groovy++ may use it at compile time.

Groovy does do some compile-time type checking, but not as much as Groovy++ (or Java). Even if the type information is not used at compile-time it will be checked at runtime, and is also valuable as a form of documentation.

Comment: please, see my update.  Of what type is your `concatenate`?  Is it `Closure<String,String,String>`?  Or what?

Comment: I accept this answer not because I'm happy with it, but this is the only one :(  Maybe, my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you aren't using Groovy++ anymore, but even if you are this may work. It certainly works for statically typed Groovy 2.x

```
interface Z {
  void callback(X x, Y y)
}

List<Y> myCollect(List<X> list, Z clos) { 
  ... 

  clos.callback(x, y)
}
```

the caller then calls it with the normal:

```
List<Y> object.myConnect(list) { X x, Y y -> 
}
```

If you leave a parameter out and have @CompileStatic, the compiler picks up missing params or bad types.

This works because a 1 method interface is equivalent to a closure in Groovy.

Comment: it also works by using Java's functional interfaces as the type of the argument, like `Function` (one-arg, one-return-value), `BiFunction` (two-args, one-return-value) or `Consumer` (one-arg, no return value).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for the answer: have a look at `@ClosureParams`, which provides IDE hints as to the expected closure parameter types